# How can I open a node edit form in an overlay (modal window)?

Tags: 8, modal-dialogs

I have a view with nodes of type 'tasks'.
I want to easily view and edit these tasks by using a minimized overlay. When I click on a task title in the view, it needs to open in an overlay.

In Drupal 7 this was possible with the core overlay module, in combination with the [Overlay Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) module.
The core overlay has been discontinued in Drupal 8, in favor of a 'back to site' link, which does not serve my purpose to show a minimized popup block. It also needs to be used by authenticated users, not only administrators.

How can this be done in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add css class `use-ajax` and `data-dialog-type="modal"` to the link. For example:

```html
<a href="/node/add/task" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal">
  Create new task
</a>
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes

Or better you can use twig variables and functions in Views like this:

```html
<a href="{{ path('node.add', {'node_type': 'task'}) }}" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal">
  Create new task
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by constructing special links with the help of [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) and [Colorbox Inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_inline). You'll probably have to create your own style for the "minimized" overlay.

There are other libraries that do the same or similar thing as Colorbox, also integrated into Drupal through a module, so you might want to search and investigate others too (Shadowbox, for example).

These modules are also worth checking out: [Modal Configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_config), [Simple Modal Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_modal_entity_form), [Entity Overlay](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_overlay).